# Trying to build from the command line, and produce a WAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, war

My folder layout is:

```
/web-inf/web.xml
/web-inf/classes/
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet{ 
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  pw.println("<html>");
  pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
  pw.println("<body>");
  pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
  pw.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

I want to do the following:

1. build everything via the command line
2. publish to Tomcat's webapps directory using a .war file

Where should I put my `HelloWorld.java` file, and how to compile it using the command line?
I believe the output of the `HelloWorld.java` goes in the `/classes/` folder.

Then how do I generate the `.war` file?

I tried just manually compiling like this:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

And I got errors relating to the imports i.e. it couldn't find the libraries in my path. Is there a Java EE library I have to download and add it to my path?

Comment: Were the source files originally created using an IDE or are you creating everything manually from the command line?

Answer (score 5):

Your code depends on the servlet API which is not in the core Java library. You will need to add it to your classpath:

```
javac -classpath $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/servlet-api.jar yourpackage/HelloWorld.java
```

WARs share the same file format as JARs (ZIP with UTF-8 filenames.) Generally, you can use ZIP utilities to work with them.

A WAR structure might look like this:

```
index.html
foo.jsp
WEB-INF/classes/yourpackage/HelloWorld.class
WEB-INF/web.xml
```

The above assumes you have a `package yourpackage;` declaration in your .java file. The default package should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If this is just a toy project it may not be worth your while, but I suggest that you adopt a serious build tool as keeping track of all the libraries you need is soon going to become an unmanageable task. The one I use is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), but there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use jar command and to add dependencies to classpath