# How to compile a Servlet from command prompt?

Tags: java, servlets, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trying to build from the command line, and produce a WAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928654/trying-to-build-from-the-command-line-and-produce-a-war-file)

It's a simple HelloWorld Servlet. I am using Windows 7 and have JDK 1.7.0 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.14 installed.

I don't know where to put files.

I don't want to use an IDE, as I want to learn how things actually work.

Comment: use **javac** from commandline

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928654/trying-to-build-from-the-command-line-and-produce-a-war-file check this

Comment: Compiling is one thing. To deploy to Tomcat, you will also need to package the compiled code as a WAR file. Hopefully one of the answers here will tell you how to do that too.

Comment: @TomAnderson You don't *have* to, but you may. As long as the files end up in the right place, it doesn't matter if it's Tomcat that unpackaged them, or they got put there manually.

Comment: @DaveNewton: True. They still need to be laid out in the right structure, though, right?

Comment: @TomAnderson Of course; that's why I put a link to the directory structure.

Comment: I know this question is very outdated, but in case some one stumbles upon this as I did, the Java servlet is a normal Java class, so you have to use javac as @TheWhiteRabbit mentioned. Refer to the javac documentation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html. To bundle the files to a WAR, you have to use the jar tool, Refer to it here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html. As for the deployment part you will have to write a script to copy the WAR file to the tomcat deployment directory and uncompress it.

Answer (score 7):

I think that's a great idea, and I wish more people did it.

As long as your source code file is in the correct package directory structure it doesn't really matter. See [this package tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html) if you need more details on that.

You'll need the Servlet API jar on the classpath when you compile, for example, if you're at the top of your source tree:

```
javac -cp path/to/servlet-api.jar;. path\to\File.java
```

You'll end up with your `.class` file in the same directory as your source, but that's fine for now. See [this classpath tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) if you have problems with your path or classpaths.

There are many places to get a Servlet API jar file, for example, in the Tomcat lib directory.

Once you're done you'll either need to create a WAR file, or deploy your app's components separately. WAR files, and web apps, follow a specific directory layout, [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-3748/aduvz/index.html).

Nutshell:

```
. (Project root)
├── WEB-INF
│   ├── classes (Your compiled classes, in project directory hierarchy)
│   │   ├── HelloWorldExample.class
│   │   ├── HelloWorldExample.java
│   │   └── LocalStrings.properties
│   ├── jsp (JSPs used as forward targets; not directory accessible to clients)
│   ├── lib (Third-party libraries, including your own)
│   │   ├── jstl.jar
│   │   └── standard.jar
│   ├── tags
│   │   └── helloWorld.tag
│   └── web.xml (Web app configruation file)
└── index.jsp (JSPs directly accessible from clients)
```

Comment: Note that on Windows (the OP mentions he uses Windows 7), you need to use \ as the path separator and `;` to separate entries in the classpath (instead of `/` and `:`).

Comment: @Jesper Oops; edited to reflect actual reality.

Answer (score 3):

Some steps.

```
C:\>set CATALINA_HOME=\rene\Tomcat_7.0.14

C:\web-app\src>javac -classpath %CATALINA_HOME%\common\lib\servlet-api.jar WebTest.java
```

WebTest.java is your servlet

Here you could find a great tutorial

[Creating a Java Web Application](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/october/13.html)

Comment: +1 for using an environment variable for the path.

Comment: Could you perhaps show how to create the WAR file too? With the class files in WEB-INF/classes, and a simple web.xml.

Comment: link I have provided has all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

For compiling servlet

```
javac -classpath C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.13\lib\servlet-api.jar HelloWorldServlet.java
```